# Enabling NUMA on IIS when migrating to Azure VMs

Tags: azure, iis, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, numa

So I'm trying to migrate a Legacy website from an AWS VM to an Azure VM and we're trying to get the same level of performance. The problem is I'm pretty new to setting up sites on IIS.

The authors of the application are long gone and we struggle with the application for many reasons. One of the problems with the site is when it's "warming up" it pulls back a ton of data to store in memory for the entire day. This involves executing long running stored procs and in memory processes which means first load of certain pages takes up to 7 minutes. It then uses a combination of in memory data and output caching to deliver the pages.

Sessions do seem to be in use although the site is capable of recovering session data from the database in some more relatively long running database operations so sessions are better to stick with where possible which is why I'm avoiding a web garden.

That's a little bit of background, however my question is really about upping the performance on IIS. When I went through their settings on the AWS box they had something call NUMA enabled with what appears to be the default settings and then the maximum worker processes set to 0 which seems to enable NUMA. I don't know why they enabled NUMA or if it was necessary, but I am trying to get as close to a like for like transition as possible and if it gives extra performance in this application we'll probably need it!

On the Azure box I can see options to set the maximum worker processes to 0 but no NUMA options. My question is whether NUMA is enabled with those default options or is there something further I need to do to enable NUMA.

Both are production sized VMs but the one on Azure I'm working with is a Standard D16s_v3 with 16 vCores and 64Gb RAM. We are load balancing across a few of them.

Comment: You might need a consultant to review your AWS VM carefully and capture all details before migration. I don't think shallow discussions here can help much.

Comment: If nothing else just some idea of understanding how NUMA works with azure VMs would help

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see the option in the Azure VM it's because the server is using symmetric processing and isn't NUMA aware.

Now to optimize your loading a bit:

1. HUGE CAVEAT - if you have memory leak type issues, don't do this!  To ensure you don't, put on a private bytes limit roughly 70% the size of memory on the server.  If you see that get hit/issue an IIS recycle (that event is logged by default) then you may want to ignore further steps.  Either that or mess around with perfmon (or more easily iteratively check peak bytes in task manager where you'll have to add that column in the details pane)
2. Change your app pool startup mode to: AlwaysRunning
3. Change your web app to preloadenabled=true
4. Set an initialization page in your web.config (so that preloading knows what to load).
5. *Edit forgot some steps.  Make sure your idle timeout is clear or set it to midnight.
6. Make sure you don't have the default recycle time enabled, clear that out.
7. If you want to get fancy you can add a loading page and set an http refresh or due further customizations seen below:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization